# Searching twitters public timeline using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, api, search, twitter

So a while back I used to use the twitter json search in one of my apps but it seems since the change in API versions there has been some major changes which even after reading the documentation I still can't get my head around and it really doesn't make it very easy to understand so hopefully one of you tech guys out there can help me out.

I want to clean my application up so it works again in plainly doing the following:-

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?
  q='+param+'&
  rpp=100&
  result_type=recent&
  lang=en
```

Obviously with the changes this is no longer possible but I want to be able to do this again using the new address but in JQuery unless someone can suggest either a tutorial or a piece of code or even a link to a topic where I could get my answer. I'm also open to using PHP as this is what I used at one point with searching Facebook's timeline and you can get an access token using `$.get()` for Facebook so surely it would be the same with Twitter too?

Any advice/code is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the search API needs authorization now. I'd say that, first off, you need to call the https url not http. 
With Abhramam William's library you'd do something like the following, after having received your app's bearer token:

`$your_tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from:grey_mina&result_type=recent&count=5");`

Comment: This is great, thank you for the advice. The only thing is from reading up on his library on GitHub it talks about getting a users authorisation where as it's not for the user to login it's so that I can just do the general search of the twitter timeline as we did so before they introduced the requirement for an access token. Twitter have made things so much more difficult now.

Comment: you can use the app tokens for that (every app has access token, token secret, user token, token secret and you can use those for searches). Alternatively store the user tokens?